# Serialise `Interface` from package reference

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm using the `protobuf-net` nuget package and have a package-specific question

---

I have a project with a core package and a main package which includes various other small packages. I have simplified this below. I was wondering, how can I serialize it from the `Core` package? Ideally, without the reference in the `Api` package as others may make their own extensions and I can't add `[ProtoInclude(...)]` in the API package for everyone.

Would it be something to do with the [Not Like Attributes](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/wiki/Getting-Started#dont-like-attributes) section? If so, is there somewhere you can point me for implementation?

**Api:**

```cs
public interface IBase
{
    string typeRef { get; }

    Connector Connector { get; set; } // Custom connector

    object Build(); // Bunch of params
}
```

**Core:**

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Main 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ICollection<IBase> Items { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Group : IBase
{
    public string typeRef => "G";
    
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Connector Connector { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string? AnExpression { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public ICollection<IBase> Items { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Base<T> : IBase
{
    public string typeRef => "S";
    
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Connector Connector { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string? Operation{ get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public IEnumerables<T?> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't know protobuf enough to tell for sure but to me it seems like a protobuf specific problem. You can serialize any of those classes without any issues with json since the properties are not inherited from external library but implemented inside the library. Worth mentioning problems with inherited properties are not under normal use circumstance but very specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Franck. My question is about the usage of the `protobuf-net` nuget package and its built-in serialiser. So, I don't believe it's a protobuf issue (but I also don't know enough about protobuf to say )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some rummaging for code and some testing, I finally got a working solution.

To limit the startup code that needed to be added to people's projects, I found a solution that only added the references once serialization was actually requested <sup>see comment 1</sup>.

The method fills the stream argument. However, I also added a byte[] method that creates a `MemoryStream`, passes that in and passes the `.ToArray()` out.

I ran into some complications with the fact that `Base<T>` has a generic type. This meant that I had to track the types that had already been added (as adding them again would throw an error). Doing this meant that if a new base was added it would still get serialised

```cs
public void SerializeTo(System.IO.Stream stream)
{
    // 1) I HAVE DONE THIS IN A METHOD (with a type tracker list)
    //    BUT YOU CAN DO IT AT RUNTIME
    if (TypeTracker.ProtoTypes == null)
    {
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Connector), true);

        // There was actually another interface,
        // so I had to add these references
        // => Group implements IGroup which implements IBase
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IGroup), false)
            .AddSubType(45, typeof(Group));

        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IBase), false)
            .AddSubType(45, typeof(IGroup));

        // DECLARE THE LIST
        TypeTracker.ProtoTypes = new List<Type>();
    }
    
    var pTypes = TypeTracker.ProtoTypes;

    // This is a IGroup
    _myGroup.PrepForSerialisation(
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IBase), false), 
        ref pTypes
    );
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, _group as FilterGroup);
}

// Group implements it as
public void PrepForSerialisation(MetaType ifilterBase, ref ICollection<Type> fTypes)
{
    foreach (var item in Items)
        if (item is ISerializer ss)
            ss.PrepForSerialisation(ifilterBase, ref fTypes);
}

// Base<T> implements it as
public void PrepForSerialisation(MetaType ifilterBase, ref ICollection<Type> fTypes)
{
    var thisType = this.GetType();

    // Make sure I've not already been defined
    if (!fTypes.Contains(thisType))
    {
        // Use the fType count, so there are never any clashes
        ifilterBase.AddSubType(50 + fTypes.Count(), thisType);

        // Add this type to the list
        fTypes.Add(thisType);
    }
}
```

In case you want to see the `TypeTracker` class

```cs
internal sealed class TypeTracker
{
    TypeTracker () { }
    
    static ICollection<Type>? _protoTypes;
    public static ICollection<Type>? ProtoTypes
    {
        get => _protoTypes;
        set
        {
            _protoTypes = value;
        }
    }
}
```